# .NET API POST Endpoint not getting hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a `.net api` and I want to test the api from a console app.
The method I am trying to test is a `POST` Method.I serialize data from my console app into a json string and I want to post it to the API, but the API does not get hit and I dont get any errors  from my console app.

My `GET` calls work though. It is just the post I cant get to work.

My API Controller->

```
using _ErrorLogger.Shared;
using _ErrorLogger.Server.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace _ErrorLogger.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ExceptionDetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IExceptionDetailsService _exceptionDetailsService;
        public ExceptionDetailsController(IExceptionDetailsService exceptionDetailsService)
        {
            _exceptionDetailsService = exceptionDetailsService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetExceptions")]
        public async Task<List<ExceptionDetails>> GetAll()
        {
            return await _exceptionDetailsService.GetAllExceptionDetails();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetExceptionByID/{id}")]
         public async Task<ExceptionDetails> GetByID(int id)
        {
            return await _exceptionDetailsService.GetExceptionDetails(id);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateException")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateException([FromBody]string obj)
        {
            //await _exceptionDetailsService.AddExceptionDetails(exceptionDetails);
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody] string obj)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

My Call from the console app ->

```
public async void ExceptionsAnalyzer(Exception exception)
        {
            HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

            StackTrace stack = new StackTrace(exception, true);

            StackFrame frame = stack.GetFrame(stack.FrameCount - 1);

            ExceptionDetails exceptionDetails = new ExceptionDetails
            {
                ExceptionMessage = exception.Message,
                InnerException = exception.InnerException?.ToString(),
                ExceptionType = exception.GetType().ToString(),
                ExceptionSourceFile = frame.GetFileName(),
                ExceptionSourceLine = frame.GetFileLineNumber().ToString(),
                ExceptionCaller = frame.GetMethod().ToString(),
                ExceptionStackTrace = exception.StackTrace,
                DateLogged = DateTime.Now

            };

            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(exceptionDetails);
            //var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:5296/api/ExceptionDetails/CreateException", json);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }
```

I am Expecting the api endpoint to be hit.

Comment: Does your debugger hit up to this point `_httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync`? Then what happend? I have just tested with your code and its hitting the API endpoint.

Comment: Have you initialized this `IExceptionDetailsService` interface DI in `program.cs` scope?

Comment: It just hits the request and then it is done. Does not even reach the if statement. All get requests work from the console app, just not the post one.

Comment: Your arguments should be of type ExceptionDetails... not type string...

Comment: Yes, its because of your method `ExceptionsAnalyzer` how you are calling this method in console app that is the main issue. Please share the full code how this `ExceptionsAnalyzer` method is executing.

Comment: What happend if you try to  use POSTMAN or other similar tools to hit that endpoint, does it work ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez, Yes not issue in `web API` side, its console method issue, non static method how come can call inside static method. This is the reason debugger stopped the execution while the request reached to this point `await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync`

Comment: There is an answer regarding that, test and upvote ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am Expecting the api endpoint to be hit.

Well, Firstly, your method in console app which is `ExceptionsAnalyzer` structure is wrong. It should be type of `static` because, `main method` within console app itself is type of `static`.

Another mistake is `async` should be type of `Task` and while calling the `ExceptionsAnalyzer` method it should be `wait()` for response but your console app is static so how it would handle `await` call? So see the solution below:

**Solution:**

```
    using System.Net.Http.Json;
    using System.Text.Json;
    
  // Calling method   
    ExceptionsAnalyzer().Wait();
  //Defining Method in dotnet 6 console app    
    static async Task ExceptionsAnalyzer()
    {
        HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var obj = "Test data";
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:5094/api/ExceptionDetails/CreateException", json);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
    
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I haven't consider your parameter `Exception exception` which you can modify yourself. I am mostly considering why you cannot get to hit API Endpoint. Hope you now got the mistake.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless `ExceptionDetails` is part of your basepath and as such is included for all API calls, I think you need to remove that.

You defined the `route` to the call as `CreateException`, so the url should be `<base url>/CreateException`

If that doesn't help, please post the code of your entire controller (with endpoint method).

Comment: I included ExceptionDetails as that is my controller name and path. Standard routing being used -> [Route("api/[controller]")]. My GET methods also use the same paths. Just the end route path differing.

Comment: Then you have to post the code of your routing. Without that, it's anyone's guess. Structurally this looks fine at a first glance, so there's likely a typo somewhere mucking things up.

Comment: I am going to edit my question and post my entire controller.

Comment: My question is updated and my controller code is now included